# docker image of rabbitmq on windows server 2019

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

im tring to install docker image of rabbitmq on window server 2019 with the next command:

```
docker run -d -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --name rabbit-test-for-medium rabbitmq:3-management
```

but Im get the next error:

```
Unable to find image 'rabbitmq:3-management' locally
3-management: Pulling from library/rabbitmq
docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

How can I solve it? please help. Thanks.

Comment: i also tried to execute: 
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name ecomm-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management.
same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running windows docker containers on your windows server. This is based on

```
docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763
```

Try swapping docker over to running linux containers either through hyper-v or wsl2

The only supported tags for 3-management for rabbitmq are
[image: picture]

these tags can be seen
[here](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq?tab=tags&page=1&name=3-management)

Comment: But that means only for the management right? May I install RabbitMQ without the management? and eventually install the management on my local machine connecting to the server instance of RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

try to running the Docker daemon in experimental mode.

1. Right click Docker instance
2. Go to Settings
3. Daemon
4. Advanced
5. Set the "experimental": true
6. Restart Docker